# Can I post a duplicate answer on a duplicate question ....with a bounty?

Tags: discussion, support

I've had this situation once before, you find a question *with* a bounty, and immediately you remember you've answered a similar question.

You cannot vote to close, since the question is "bountied", but still it is a dupe, so answering seems incorrect. Options seem to clash.

What to do?

These are the questions: [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696639/how-to-navigate-between-monitors-using-the-mouse-in-a-circular-way?noredirect=1#comment1032244_696639) (with a bountie) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692836/3-monitors-how-to-move-from-screen-1-to-screen-3-by-moving-cursor-to-the-left/693003#693003) (original answer)

Comment: A mod can refund the bounty and close it. What does the OP say?

Comment: @muru I'll ask him, but he seems to agree it is a dupe.

Comment: If you can adapt your old answer a bit to the new question, I'd write it again, but modified. If it would be perfect exactly as the original answer already is, asking a mod to refund the bounty (as muru already said) would be the best in my personal opinion.

Comment: @ByteCommander OP seems to feel like giving the bounty to an answer, linking to a similarly looking solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the very close similarities between the two questions - the fact that it is similarly worded - together that the OP has themselves confirmed this means a return of the bounty is in order.

To tidy up I've duped the question and merged the answers.

The latter action is needed so that the auto resolution feature of Stack Exchange works - people are automatically directed to the correct question and its answers.

If the OP wishes they can rebounty the original question and reward whichever answer is most relevant to them.

Comment: Thanks, seems the perfect solution to me.